# HttpBuilder in grails script

Tags: grails, httpbuilder

I have a problem with the HttpBuilder and grails. If I try to use it in a grails script it doesn't work...how can I import it in a script?
I tried with Grape but it is too slow....is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the Grails Rest plugin. It enables the use of HttpBuilder in a Grails project:
http://grails.org/plugin/rest

Answer (score 0):

Specify http-builder dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
   runtime "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2"
 }
```

Comment: ClassNotFoundError because when the script is executed that JAR isn't loaded yet, I think that a possible solution is to set up the entire application, but I don't like this solution very much...

Comment: I believe that HttpBuilder classes will available for your script if you specify dependency correctly.